# Does Java-8 support product of elements of array

Tags: java, java-8

Java-8 provides stream to sum the array as following, does the stream support `product`? If steam doesn't support, is there other way to calculate the product without manually writing my loop?

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int sum = IntStream.of(a).sum();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sum` and others are just shortcuts to specific `reduce` calls.

> **sum**: Returns the sum of elements in this stream. This is a special case of
>   a reduction and is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  return reduce(0, Integer::sum);
> ```
>
> **Reduce**: Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using the
>   provided identity value and an associative accumulation function, and
>   returns the reduced value.

Then you can write something like:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int prod = IntStream.of(a).reduce(1,(x,y)->x*y);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try it with the [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) method. Something like below:

```java
int product = IntStream.of(a)
    .reduce((i, j) -> i * j)
    .orElse(1); // fallback value if stream is empty
```